# MySqlRouter cant connect to MySqlServer

Tags: mysql, mysqlrouter

mysqlrouter service is running

ports are listening

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6446            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6150/mysqlrouter
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6447            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6150/mysqlrouter
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6448            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6150/mysqlrouter
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6449            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6150/mysqlrouter
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6150/mysqlrouter
```

but when I try to connect using mysql client from different computer

```
mysql -u innodbcluster -h 192.168.11.124 -P 6446 -p
```

it says

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
> '192.168.11.124:6446' (10060)

what am I missing?

PS I installed the mysqlrouter in the primary mysqlserver
am I correct or it should be installed in the application thats going to connect to the innodbcluster?

Answer (score 0):

mysqlrouter should be installed in the application that is going to connect to innodbcluster